# Removing the hash from the URL in Vue JS + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-routing

I'm developing an app using laravel and vue js and I'm trying to remove the `#` from my URL. Normally my url looks something like this.

```
http://localhost/foo/?#/admin
```

Having these settings with `App.js`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes,
});
```

And `web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('base');
});
```

But after changing these settings. I got the expected URL like this. `http://localhost/foo/admin`. But the problem is the page is not having a load or rendering basically my page became a blank page.

with the settings of `App.js`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes,
});
```

And `web.php`

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('base');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

I have followed every solution I got from different forum, but it seems it didn't work on my end.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you are in history mode

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes,
});
```

Import all of your routes dynamically

For example

```js
import HelloWorld from "./views/HelloWorld.vue"
```

Becomes

```js
{
   path: "/login",
   name: "login",
   component: () => import("./views/HelloWorld.vue")
}
```

In `app.vue`

Ensure that you have your `<router-view>` component bound to a key

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

I would also suggest adding a [dynamic route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) to the end of your `routes.js` file, to catch any 404 errors.

Comment: Hi Nigel, if I recall correctly (it has been a long time since I have used larvel) using `import Foobar from './pages/Foobar ';` is not the right way to do this... instead on each route use ` component: () => import("./pages/Foobar.vue")`

Comment: A newbie here and still exploring the vue routes XD. I already change my route that my `mode` is in history.

And this is how I declare every path in my `routes.js`

`import Login from './pages/Login';`

`{path: '/admin', component: Login, meta: {requiresAuth: false}},`

and on how I import my `routes.js` into `app.js`

`import routes from './routes';`

Comment: Noted, let me try that. Hopefully it goes well.

Comment: I did that but the bug still the same. You think there's more file that I need to change?